# Using Typescript paths mapping in Angular library

Tags: angular, typescript, tsconfig

I'm currently developing a small Angular library. To shorten some imports I've used `paths` mapping in `tsconfig.json`. However, after building the library, imports in emitted `.js` files (in ES2015 version) are not changed, because the path mapping is for Typescript transpiler only.

My question is, how can I assure the imports have the right paths without having to sacrifice the `paths` mapping functionality. I've read an [issue on GitHub about the module paths in emitted files](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10866) but haven't found any suitable solution.